# Error in reading bitmap - java.io.FileNotFoundException: ../files/app/assets/icon.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: angular, webpack, nativescript

This error appears after upgrading to nativescript 8.

my project structure is:

```
src
- app
- assets
- fonts
```

my Webpack file contains:

const copyTargets = [{ from: { glob: 'assets/**', dot: false } }, { from: { glob: 'fonts/**', dot: false } }, ...copyReplacements];
new CopyWebpackPlugin([...copyTargets, { from: { glob: '**/*.jpg', dot: false } }, { from: { glob: '**/*.png', dot: false } }], copyIgnore),

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's in your webpack.config.ts

```
const copyTargets = [
   { from: { glob: 'assets/', dots: false } },  // note that dots not dot. 
   { from: { glob: 'fonts/', dot: false } } // note that dots not dot. 
];

new CopyWebpackPlugin = ([...copyTargets], copyIgnore); // no need to re add your globs again.
```

Please tell me if you fix this.